# unable to install mysql bulk plugin in fluentd

Tags: rubygems, fluentd

Hi I have recently started working on fluent d ,i need to install the 
MySQL bulk plugin as specified in this URL

OS : centos 7

https://github.com/toyama0919/fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk as specified in this url
when i run command gem install fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk

getting error as 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Tried from sbin folder as well

cd /opt/td-agent/usr/sbin/
[root@hyd-cms-camaign-lsrv2 sbin]# td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-mysql
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'fluent-plugin-mysql' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Tried with URl:

https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-mysql

But still ,same error

executed following command.
gem install fluent-plugin-mysql

Could not find a valid gem 'fluent-plugin-mysql' (>= 0), here is why:
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[root@hyd-cms-camaign-lsrv2 appuser]#           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

See README. https://github.com/toyama0919/fluent-plugin-mysql-bulk

> Deprecated : This plugin had been merged to fluent-plugin-mysql. This plugin is not maintained anymore!!!!!

Use fluent-plugin-mysql instead.
https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-mysql

Comment: Hi @Toru Thanks for your help,But is tiil got the same error                                                             gem install fluent-plugin-mysql
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'fluent-plugin-mysql' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)